# Backbone events not firing after rendered view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a view being rendered in the router, but after it's rendered none of the events will fire. The following is my view:

```
function(Global, util, user, userMenu) { 
        /*userMenu is the template*/
        var UserMenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                this.template = _.template(userMenu);
            },
            render: function() {
                var container = $(this.el);
                container.empty().append(this.template());
                return container;
            },
            events: {
                "tap #about-user-menu" : "launchAbout",
                "keydown #about-user-menu": function(e) { if (e.which === 13) this.launchAbout(e); },
                "tap #help-user-menu" : "launchHelp",
                "keydown #help-user-menu": function(e) { if (e.which === 13) this.launchHelp(e); },
                "tap #resources-user-menu" : "launchResources",
                "keydown #resources-user-menu": function(e) { if (e.which === 13) this.launchResources(e); },
            },
            launchAbout: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("about");
            },
            launchHelp: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("help");
            },
            launchResources: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("resources");
            }
        });
        return UserMenuView;
    }
```

This is how I am rendering the view in the router:

```
showUserMenu: function(){
    var userMenu = new UserMenuView();
    userMenu.render();
}
```

Comment: show the code how you are appending in parent View

Comment: @aktiv-coder sorry, I'm actually rendering in the router. I've edited the question to show that. I've tried your answer but it didn't work

Comment: You never add the view's `el` to the page nor do you pass an `el` into the view.

Comment: @pedrumgolriz where are you appending el to DOM?

Comment: @aktiv-coder I'm applying the template to the DOM, `_.template(userMenu)`

Comment: When I add `el: '#menu'` the view will no longer render

Comment: I'm applying the template to the DOM, how?, _.template(userMenu) will return you just HTML and must append to the DOM. answer updated. but i am not sure

Answer (score 1):

`this.template()` in your code returns just a HTML string, causing the problem.

so you should try to append `el` element of view which has `HTML`string and also `Event bindings`

now in  your view assign `HTML` to `el`

```
render: function() {
           this.$el.html(this.template());
           return this;
          }
```

in your router

```
$('#menu').append(UserMenuView.render().el);
```